# Qual è il significato di "sgrossare" in questo brano?

Tags: word-meaning, verbs

Nella versione in italiano dell'episodio *Gioco del matto soto la croce* (o *I crozadór*) di *Mistero buffo*, di Dario Fo, ho letto:

> In questo modo combineranno il grande spettacolo del tuo 
>   patimento. Bel salvamento che fai! Allargato come un uccello ti spiaccicheranno anche sopra gli scudi e le targhe di 
>   guerra... e anche sulle bandiere ci sarà pittata la tua croce a lustri colori (*continua a recitare a ritmo sostenuto*), e sarai sulle spade ad accoppare, a stracciare, in nome di Dio e infilzare le donne, gli uomini e i bambini 
>   tutti! **Sgrossare** e scannare in nome del tuo segno! Bella truffalderia combineranno col tuo sacrificio!

Ho cercato il verbo "sgrossare" in parecchi dizionari, ma le accezioni che ho trovato non sembrano avere senso in questo contesto. Per questa ragione vi chiedo: sapreste spiegarmi qual è il significato di "sgrossare" nel brano sopra citato?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tutti i verbi utilizzati fanno riferimento all'uccisione di persone (*accoppare, stracciare, scannare...*); in questo caso si utilizza nello stesso senso di eliminare fisicamente "il grosso" delle persone. Si potrebbe utilizzare come sinonimo "decimare", ma "sgrossare" è più truculento e dà l'idea di uccisioni di massa e sbrigative.

Non ho letto il libro, ma immagino che a parlare sia "il matto", che in qualità di matto ha il coraggio di dire verità che nessun altro proferisce, ovvero che il sacrificio del Signore nel futuro servirà come giustificazione a dei macellai di carne umana (da notare appunto l'uso di *scannare* e *accoppare*) per uccidere e sterminare.

Comment: Effettivamente è il matto quello che dice queste parole.